# How can I code a menu for tkinter on python so the user can only select one option?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

```
mb = tk.Menubutton(top, text="Walk length", relief=tk.RAISED)
mb.grid()
submenu = tk.Menu(mb, tearoff=0)
first_var = tk.IntVar()
second_var = tk.IntVar()
third_var = tk.IntVar()
fourth_var = tk.IntVar()

submenu.add_checkbutton(label="1-5km", variable=first_var)
submenu.add_checkbutton(label="5-10km", variable=second_var)
submenu.add_checkbutton(label="10-15km", variable=third_var)
submenu.add_checkbutton(label="15-20km", variable=fourth_var)

mb['menu'] = submenu
```

At the moment the user is allowed to select multiple options however I want the code to allow the user to select one option

Answer (score 1):

The widget you are looking for is a radio button

here is an example of radio button:

```
import tkinter as Tkinter
parent_widget = Tkinter.Tk()
v = Tkinter.StringVar()
v.set(1) # sets default to 1

radiobutton_widget1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(parent_widget,
                                   text="1-5Km",
                                   variable=v, value="1-5")
radiobutton_widget2 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(parent_widget,
                                   text="5-10",
                                   variable=v, value="5-10")


radiobutton_widget1.pack()
radiobutton_widget2.pack()
Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_radiobutton(...)` instead of `add_checkbutton(...)`:

```py
my_var = tk.StringVar()

submenu.add_radiobutton(label="1-5km", variable=my_var)
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="5-10km", variable=my_var)
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="10-15km", variable=my_var)
submenu.add_radiobutton(label="15-20km", variable=my_var)
```